# Optimisation of dependence of efficiency of CNN on training data

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, regression

I got a large dataset of images (dimensions of 16 x 16, 250k samples) and corresponding spherical coordinates (distributed uniformly in each coordinate). On these, I trained a convolutional regression network to directly yield the coordinates for a provided image. The network itself is rather simple and consists of multiple convolutional layers where the last of them is flattened and followed by some dense layers to get the desired output. Since the input image size is rather small, pooling layers are obsolete I think (doesn't make much difference if used).

If I now train on all of the data I will get reasonable results in the end. But, if I filter them before training, i.e. only use coordinates which are limited by a certain radius, the network will increase it's performance quite a bit, but will only work well if my input image corresponds to the parameter space used during training.

So my question is, if the network isn't deep enough or has the wrong architecture to perform on the complete dataset with high confidence or if this is expected behaviour. One naive approach would be to train the network for different coordinate ranges and to store the weights for each of them. Then, you could train a classifier to decide in which range you are and use the previously determined weights for the network accordingly. But this seems strange to me, as a single network should somehow be able to achieve the same without this weird architecture, I think.

I would be pleased if someone has an idea how I could optimise the performance of my network to yield the best results over the whole coordinate space.